# Funduino Uno with 5V 1A power supply?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, voltage-level

Can I use a "Funduino Uno" arduino with power from a power bank with DC 5V 1A output?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as it connects the the arduino clone via USB and can maintain a stable power output then it's suitable.